# Image Upload like Plupload on JSF

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using the primefaces library on my JSF project, and the component

```
<p:fileUpload />
```

is a little bit more simple to a image upload.

I need a JSF Component like a Plupload (www.plupload.com), but searching on the internet I haven't found it.

If don't have a JSF component like a plupload, is possible, and if is, how I do a image upload with image upload order, thumbnails and this simple and necessary things in a image upload management.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement it by yourself, to make a composite or more likely a custom component. You can see here: [When to use , tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)  where @BalusC  describes the different approaches.

Answer (score -2):

JSF2.2 have fileupload tag , also you can use primefaces or tomahawk myfaces, also you can extend